# Convert Sql Query to Criteria Query

Tags: hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have these entities mapped like this:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="work_stage")
 public class WorkStage {
   @Id
   private BigDecimal id;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(name = "work_stage_x_locality", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_work_stage"),
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_locality"))
   private List<Locality> localityList;
}

 @Entity
 @Table(name="locality")
 public class Locality {
   @Id
   private BigDecimal id;  
   @Column(name="name")
   private String name;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "localityList")
   private List<WorkStage> workStageList;
}
```

I would like to do the following query using the Criteria API:

```
select * from work_stage
where id in (
select ws.id from work_stage ws inner join work_stage_x_locality wsl on ws.id = wsl.id_work_stage 
where wsl.id_locality in (74, 75, 76));
```

I tried writing that join within a subquery but with no advance.

Later Edit:
I was able to write the inner select like this:

```
Expression<String> exp = root.join(sqlQuery.getKey()).get("id");
predicates.add(exp.in((List<BigDecimal>) sqlQuery.getValue()))
```

Comment: If you ignore the outer query for a moment, can you implement the subquery?

Comment: So, for the moment I have reached this point:                                       `CriteriaQuery<WorkStage> query = builder.createQuery(WorkStage.class);
 Subquery<BigDecimal> subqueryWorkStageId = query.subquery(BigDecimal.class);
Root<WorkStage> subqueryWorkStageRoot = subqueryWorkStageId.from(WorkStage.class);
                subqueryWorkStageId.select(subqueryWorkStageRoot.get("id"))                      .where(subqueryWorkStageRoot.join("localityList").in((List<BigDecimal>) sqlQuery.getValue()));`

Comment: If there are not too many ids in the result, then you not necessarily need a subquery. You can load the ids as a query, build some collection and use that as a parameter for the filter of the main query.

Comment: I'm quite new to CriteriaApi, been reading the documentation for a couple hours now. 
I am trying to get this type of query as a predicate so that I can send it to the JpaRepository, and I'm not quite sure how to retrieve that collection that you are mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

So how I have managed to write it was like this:

```
CriteriaQuery<WorkStage> query = builder.createQuery(WorkStage.class);
               Subquery<BigDecimal> subqueryWorkStageId = query.subquery(BigDecimal.class);
               Root<WorkStage> subqueryWorkStageRoot = subqueryWorkStageId.from(WorkStage.class);
               subqueryWorkStageId.select(subqueryWorkStageRoot.get("id"))
                       .where(subqueryWorkStageRoot.join("localityList")
                               .in((List<BigDecimal>) sqlQuery.getValue()));

               predicates.add(query.select(root)
                       .where(root.get("id").in(subqueryWorkStageId)).getRestriction());
```